# How to use python f string to replace format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am saving some urls in my constants.py file like this:

```
BASE_URL = 'https://{env}.my-site.com'
ENV_URLS = {
    'dev': BASE_URL.format(env='dev'),
    'demo': BASE_URL.format(env='demo'),
    'prod': BASE_URL.format(env='prod')
}
```

This is done using old `.format()`, how can I achieve same result with python's new `f-string formatting`?

Comment: Just stick with `format`. f-strings are not universally superior.

Comment: You can’t without repeating the string three times, which is probably exactly what this code tries to prevent. In other words, f-strings won’t be an *improvement* here.

Comment: ...although, the existing code is needlessly repetitive, and shortening it with a dict comprehension then makes it simple to introduce an f-string. Still, it's not always a good idea to use f-strings.

Comment: The point of f-strings is to insert variables into constant templates. This code inserts constants into a variable template. Notwithstanding the actual syntax, how do you *logically* intend f-strings to be used here?

Answer (score 6):

f-strings aren't a goal in and of themselves. If it doesn't look like f-strings will improve a piece of code, there's no reason to search for a way to force them in.

That said, this code is needlessly repetitive. It could be shortened with a dict comprehension:

```
ENV_URLS = {env: BASE_URL.format(env=env) for env in ['dev', 'demo', 'prod']}
```

and then if you want to use an f-string, it's easy to do so:

```
ENV_URLS = {env: f'https://{env}.my-site.com' for env in ['dev', 'demo', 'prod']}
```